# Check box is not coming in Request.Form (NameValueCollection)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I create one Method in MVC 4.0 which taking the Request.Form (Namevaluecollection) in Form. I faced below issue in checkbox and radio button.

I added dynamically checkbox or radio button with below code, and I set the form value collection as "`NameValueCollection formsCollection = Request.Form`" in one of my controller method but that checkbox or radio button is not coming in "`formsCollection.AllKeys`" while other control like text box, text area, dropdown will work properly.

```
<form>
    <div class="divLeft div1" id="div83ac0fad-41d5-40e5-99cd-f99ea8877b04">
       <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Checkbox 2</label>
         <div class="controls">
             <div id="cfCheckbox">
                <label>Option 1</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox83ac0fad-41d5-40e5-99cd-f99ea8877b04" name="checkbox83ac0fad-41d5-40e5-99cd-f99ea8877b04">&nbsp;
                <label>Option2</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox83ac0fad-41d5-40e5-99cd-f99ea8877b04"  name="checkbox83ac0fad-41d5-40e5-99cd-f99ea8877b04">&nbsp;
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove Id or make them unique. Just keep name equal.

Comment: This makes no sense. You have the same name for both checkboxes. Since unchecked checkboxes do not post back, you could get nothing posted back (both unchecked), 2 duplicates, or just 1 (how would you know which one was checked). Learn the basics of MVC, in particular how to use view models and strongly typed helpers to generate correct html and bind to your model when you post back.

Answer (score 0):

You're having `id="checkbox83ac0fad-41d5-40e5-99cd-f99ea8877b04"` on both check-boxes and the main `div`. *IDs* in `HTML` are supposed to be unique.

Remove the *IDs* on the checkboxes. This should fix your problem.

`FormsCollection` uses `Name` for binding, not `ID`. So you don't really need your elements to have IDs.

Comment: I remove the Id from check box but still not getting success to save it.

Comment: I generate unique id for check box and assign to it, but still that check box(es) is not coming in Request.Form

Comment: back code is below

function void GenerateDetail(EntityDetail ED){
  NameValueCollection formsCollection = Request.Form;

  var item = from key in formsCollection.AllKeys
             select key;
}